# Send document with default e-mail client

Tags: .net, windows, api, email

For example, when you click a link in your web browser, it automatically opens default e-mail client installed on your PC and fills that e-mail address in. I need to perform similar operation, but with file attachment. It will look like "Send file with default e-mail client" option in the software interface.

Is there any API available for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send email using default email client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809538/how-to-send-email-using-default-email-client)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality you are talking about uses the `mailto:` URL scheme, described in this [RFC](http://ftp.ics.uci.edu/pub/ietf/uri/rfc2368.txt).

This has no provisions for attachments, so the answer is that, no there is no such API.

You can create your own webform and send email from the server side - this will give you all the control you need over email messages.

Answer (score 1):

An API I dont't known. For a simple solution to start the email-client with an address you can use:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:"+emailAddress);
```

But its only for simple single emails and the limitations are obvious. Make sure to catch the exceptions that could be thrown.

**Update** 
*I Have not seen the attachment requirement. Can not help in this case but anyhow here sample-code if you have outlook and the interops installed. Maybe it helps you:*

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = 
         new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem=
         app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);         
 mailItem.Attachments.Add(filePath);
 // ....
```