# Hyperlink an Email Address using LinkLabel in C#

Tags: c#, email, hyperlink, outlook, linklabel

I have made an about box that is meant to allow users to click the hyperlink email address which will take them to a Microsoft Outlook to be able to send an email to the email address, but I don't know how to link it to Outlook and allow the user to click the link to do this

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You are not saying whether you are using Win- or WebForms...in WinForms I think you need to create an event-handler for the click event. Inside that you can start the default mail application by typing:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:youremail@xx.com");
```

Comment: It's worth noting here that if the user doesn't have a default mail-client set up in Win XP/7 this call will throw an exception `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): No application is associated with the specified file for this operation`. Win 8 will at least ask them what app they wish to launch the "mailto" handler with

Comment: @Xerxes , how do we avoid this error or can we catch it and ask for which app to launch?

Answer (score 6):

Check this SO thread:

[How to send email using default email client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809538/winforms-how-to-send-email-using-default-email-client)

Basically, the click event would be something like this:

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender,System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
 System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "mailto:someone@somewhere.com?subject=hello&body=love my body";
    proc.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a `LinkLabel` like this in the form's constructor:

```cs
linkLabel1.Links.Add(new LinkLabel.Link(0, linkLabel1.Text.Length, "mailto:bob@someaddress.com"));
```

Then, in the `LinkLabel`'s click handler:

```cs
linkLabel1.Links[linkLabel1.Links.IndexOf(e.Link)].Visited = true;
string target = e.Link.LinkData as string;
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(target);
```

Answer (score 2):

`<a href="mailto:bob@someaddress.com"></a>.`

If outlook is installed on the user's machine it will use it.

Edit:  oops just noticed you wanted Winforms not web.

For winforms use `System.Diagnositcs.Process.Start(outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m bob@someadress.com)` in the click event handler.

Answer (score 2):

Put a link label on your form.

Double-click the link-label to create your on click handler then put the system process call in it like this:

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    linkLabel1.LinkVisited = true;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:info@cybersprocket.com");
}
```

That will fire off the default email application that the user has configured on their windows box.

Replace the mailto: with a HTTP reference to open a web page in their default browser:

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    linkLabel1.LinkVisited = true;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.cybersprocket.com");
}
```