# How to create SendTo mail recipient feature in C# Windows Form Application?

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send email using default email client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809538/how-to-send-email-using-default-email-client)

How can I create SendTo mail recipient feature in C# Windows Form Application? Something like this:

[image: Send to Mail recipient]

I need to open the Default Email client in the system and users allowed to enter to address, subject, mail body etc.

I found some code in C++ but I am looking for managed or WIN32 API code.

Comment: @Hans Passant I require this feature in Windows Form application. Its programming related.

Comment: Yes it will open the default mail client. But its not attaching the file :(

Comment: Here's an example:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809538/how-to-send-email-using-default-email-client

Cheers

Comment: Why in windows forms would want bring up another application to send a mail?

Comment: I need to incorporate a feature like I want to send my applications output file as email attachment.

Comment: I got the answer : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/SendFileToNET.aspx thanks to :@mrlucmorin :)

Comment: Well, that was completely unguessable from the question.  Why on Earth didn't you mention that?  Use the MailMessage.Attachments property.  The capability to specify attachments with external mailers that accept the mailto protocol has been removed a long time ago due to widespread abuse.

Answer (score 1):

Try [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) if you know all details of the message and just want to send it.

If you need to invoke the mail client, you can use [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx) and pass it a mailto: link.  There are some good examples of crafting mailto links on the web, I found [this one](http://www.outfront.net/tutorials_02/adv_tech/mailto.htm).

Comment: But it won't open email client. Also I need option for users to enter email address. :(

Comment: Got it!  I edited my answer, adding one way you can invoke the user's default mail client.

Comment: Yes its working, but I want to attach the file also. Like Send To mail recipient works.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you may be looking for.

1. Visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767737(VS.85).aspx and read up on the mailto syntax.
2. Visit http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/02/24/sending-files-via-the-default-e-mail-client.aspx and see that there is an example on using the mailto format to load the default email client on a machine using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`

Comment: I know this. But I want to popup the default email client. :(